# How to get current operating system language?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I am newbie to mfc, and I got struck over how to get the current operating system language (Ex: If it is English operating system I must get it as English and locale can be different. For English OS locale can be Japanese vice versa).

Current locale I am getting it through `GetSystemDefaultLangID` and the only thing I was left with is I need to get the current operating system language.

Can anyone kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you need `GetUserDefaultUILanguage`. The system's settings and user settings may not be the same.

[User Interface Language Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
int wmain()
{
    wcout << "GetUserDefaultUILanguage:   " << GetUserDefaultUILanguage() << "\n";
    wcout << "GetSystemDefaultUILanguage: " << GetSystemDefaultUILanguage() << "\n";
    wcout << "\n";
    wcout << "GetUserDefaultLangID:       " << GetUserDefaultLangID() << "\n";
    wcout << "GetSystemDefaultLangID:     " << GetSystemDefaultLangID() << "\n";
    wcout << "\n";
    wcout << "GetUserDefaultLCID:         " << GetUserDefaultLCID() << "\n";
    wcout << "GetSystemDefaultLCID:       " << GetSystemDefaultLCID() << "\n";
    wcout << "\n";

    wchar_t buf[100];
    LCID lcid = GetUserDefaultLCID();
    cout << "GetUserDefaultLCID: " << "\n";
    if (GetLocaleInfo(lcid, LOCALE_ILANGUAGE, buf, 100)) wcout << buf << "\n";
    if (GetLocaleInfo(lcid, LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, buf, 100))  wcout << buf << "\n";
    if (GetLocaleInfo(lcid, LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME, buf, 100)) wcout << buf << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```