# Get current Windows language

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I want to get the name of the language selected by user now, not the default language.

However, this code:

```
TCHAR loc[80];
GetLocaleInfoA(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, loc, 80*sizeof(TCHAR));
```

returns only default language.

I have searched what first parameter should i use to get current lang, but failed to find it.

Comment: GetThreadUILanguage(), probably.

Comment: Considering that no Microsoft program, not even Windows itself, manages to correctly identify which language the user has chosen (I always get an annoying mixture of Norwegian and English), and considering that they, maybe for that reason, tie a lot of functionality to the incorrectly identified chosen language, I recommend making **your own scheme**, not relying on Windows' settings  --  because you can't do a better job than Microsoft about that, and what they do sucks. Once they even had the MFC class wizard functionality tied to that. It's incredible, and very sad.

Comment: [GetSystemDefaultUILanguage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/Dd318123(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: There is no such thing as *the* language, selected by a user. There's a default GUI language, an input language, regional settings for date and currency formatting, etc. What are you looking for?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/30229657/4603670